# If statement not equal to

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RockPaperScissors
 {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1: Choose rock, paper or scissors: ");
    String Player1 = scan.next().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Player 2: Choose rock, paper or scissors: ");
    String Player2 = scan.next().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println ("Player 1 chose " + Player1);
    System.out.println ("Player 2 chose " + Player2);

    if (Player1.!equals("rock" + "paper" + "scissors")
    {
        System.out.println ("Please insert either Rock Paper or Scissors!);
    }
    if (Player1.equals(Player2))
    {
        System.out.println ("Its a tie!");
    }
    if ((Player1.equals("rock")) && (Player2.equals("paper")))
    {
        System.out.println ("Player 2 wins!");
    }
    else if ((Player1.equals("paper")) && (Player2.equals("rock")))
    {
        System.out.println ("Player 1 wins!");
    }
    if ((Player1.equals("scissors")) && (Player2.equals("paper")))
    {
        System.out.println ("Player 1 wins!");
    }
    else if ((Player1.equals("paper")) && (Player2.equals("scissors")))
    {
        System.out.println ("Player 2 wins!");
    }
    if ((Player1.equals("rock")) && (Player2.equals("scissors")))
    {
        System.out.println ("Player 1 wins!");
    }
    else if ((Player1.equals("scissors")) && (Player2.equals("rock")))
    {
        System.out.println ("Player 2 wins!");
    }


}
```

}

I have made a simple Rock Scissors Paper game, however I want to implement validation so the user will be notified if they enter anything other than Rock Paper Scissors. I had a go with `.!equals` however I'm getting an error saying `<identifier>` expected.

Thanks!

Comment: "if (!Player1.equals("rock" + "paper" + "scissors")" (mind the ! /before/ the "Player1") and it's also missing a ")"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrong syntax:

```
Player1.!equals
```

change to:

```
!Player1.equals
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is

```
if (!Player1.equals("rock" + "paper" + "scissors"))
```

This won't serve your purpose anyway, it should be:

```
if (!Player1.equals("rock") 
    && !Player1.equals("paper") 
    && !Player1.equals("scissors"))
```

or the equivalent

```
if (!(Player1.equals("rock")
    || Player1.equals("paper") 
    || Player1.equals("scissors")))
```

The `+` operator concatenates Strings, so you would be comparing `Player1` with `"rockpaperscissors"`

---

As a sidenote, you should:

- respect Java conventions, and start you var names with a lower case letter (`player1` instead of `Player1`)
- extract your fixed String to constants (`private static final String PAPER = "paper";` as a class attribute)
- invoke `.equals()` on constants when possible, in order to avoid a `NullPointerException` (using `PAPER.equals(player1)`)

All in all, your code would look like:

```java
if (!ROCK.equals(player1) 
    && !PAPER.equals(player1) 
    && !SCISSORS.equals(player1))
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
  if (!Player1.equals("rock" + "paper" + "scissors")
{
    System.out.println ("Please insert either Rock Paper or Scissors!);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't even compile you need something like this:

```
if (!Player1.equals("rock") && !Player1.equals("paper") && !Player1.equals("scissors")) {
   System.out.println ("Please insert either Rock Paper or Scissors!);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the syntax, the test is logically wrong.  This:

```
if (!Player1.equals("rock" + "paper" + "scissors")) {
```

means the same think as this:

```
if (!Player1.equals("rockpaperscissors")) {
```

What you really need is something like this:

```
if (!(Player1.equals("rock") || 
      Player1.equals("paper") || 
      Player1.equals("scissors"))) {
```

... and the rest of the logic is a bit broken too.

---

Finally, I should point out that `Player1` and `Player2` should be `player1` and `player2` respectively.  A variable name should never start with an uppercase letter.  It is a big stylistic no-no.